# Retrofit respone null in Data Class

Tags: kotlin, retrofit2

I'm a newbie about Kotlin. My first project is to consume a rest api. I already made that using retrofit. But I have a problem when I'm logging the response, my data class is null. I don't know where is the error.

**My Rerofit Client**

```
object RetrofitClient {
    var retrofit: Retrofit? = null

    fun getClient(baseUrl: String): Retrofit? {
        if (retrofit == null) {
            //TODO While release in Google Play Change the Level to NONE
            val interceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
            interceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
            val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(interceptor)
                .connectTimeout(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build()

            retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .client(client)
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build()
        }

        return retrofit

    }
}
```

**My Interface**

```
public interface ApiLoginService {

    @POST("UserManagementCoreAPI/api/v1/users")
    fun loginService(@Body request: RequestBody): Call<DataLogin>
}


object ApiUtils {

    val BASE_URL = "------"

    val apiLoginService: ApiLoginService
        get() = RetrofitClient.getClient(BASE_URL)!!.create(ApiLoginService::class.java)

}
```

**My class data**

```
data class DataLogin (
    @SerializedName("employeeId") val employeeId : String,
    @SerializedName("fullName") val fullName : String,
    @SerializedName("loginConfins") val loginConfins : String,
    @SerializedName("branchId") val branchId : String,
    @SerializedName("isActive") val isActive : String
)
```

**Main Activity**

```
mApiLoginService!!.loginService(requestBody).enqueue(object : Callback<DataLogin>{
                    override fun onResponse(call: Call<DataLogin>, response: Response<DataLogin>) {
                        if(response.isSuccessful()){
                            if(response.body().toString() == null){
                                Log.d(tag,"Null")
                            }else{
                                Log.d(tag,"Logging In  " + response.body()!!)
                                progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
                                btn_submit.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                                startActivity(Intent(this@MainActivity, HomeActivity::class.java))
                            }
                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Invalid username or password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                            Log.d(tag,"Error  " + response.errorBody().toString())
                            progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
                            btn_submit.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                        }
                    }
                    override fun onFailure(call: Call<DataLogin>, t: Throwable) {
                        progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
                        btn_submit.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    }
                })
```

**My Respone Log**

```
message: Logging In  DataLogin(employeeId=null, fullName=null, loginConfins=null, branchId=null, isActive=null)
```

I don't know where is the error and why my data is null. If the response succeeds is still gives me null.

This is a postman example
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an issue with your schema , Your DataLogin class is different of your postman schema , Retrofit is waiting for : fullName, isActive ...., and the response is : header , data .. , you have to create class that contains header as variable of type `Header(errors:List<AnotherClass>)`, data as variable of type `Data(data(List<DataLogin>),totalRecord:Int)`, i would suggest if you use helper website like [JSON to Class](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) , parse your postman response there , and he will give you your correct response class but it's will be in java , you have to rewrite the code yourself of just copy paste in android studio and he will convert the code to Kotlin for you. (in the web site , check Source type: JSON)

Comment: Thank you very much it works. But i have another question. How to display just data(List<DataLogin> ?

Comment: This should be from your API first, you are pushing objects into data array , and then putting this data array inside another data object, you have to change your outer data field to array and then push objects directly inside it (object : employeeId,fullname,...)

Comment: This is output when im Log.d Data = DataLogin(data=Data(data=[DataX(branchId=999, employeeId=david999  , fullName=MUHAMMAD DAVID, isActive=true, loginConfins=david999    )], totalRecord=1), header=Header(errors=[])). How to show just this data DataX(branchId=999, employeeId=david999  , fullName=MUHAMMAD DAVID, isActive=true, loginConfins=david999    ) ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to match the json structure with your data classes if you do not provide a custom adapter to Gson. So if you want to have a result, maybe something like this will work:

```
data class Response(
    @SerializedName("headers") val headers: List<Any>,
    @SerializedName("data") val data: Data
)

data class Data(
    @SerializedName("data") val data: List<DataLogin>,
    @SerializedName("totalRecord") val totalRecord: Int
)

data class DataLogin (
    @SerializedName("employeeId") val employeeId : String,
    @SerializedName("fullName") val fullName : String,
    @SerializedName("loginConfins") val loginConfins : String,
    @SerializedName("branchId") val branchId : String,
    @SerializedName("isActive") val isActive : String
)
```

You need to return a Response object from your retrofit call.

Also a few tips about kotlin, Gson works well for Java, but it has some issues with kotlin (about null safety). I use Moshi when the project language is kotlin and it works well with it.

Try to avoid using `!!` in kotlin because it will cause RuntimeException. There are other ways of checking null and to protect your code from RuntimeExceptions.